# Can't find Build Action in properties panel - Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am building an app using Xamarin forms with visual studio 2022 I want to embedded resource a car image which is in drawable folder but Build Action does not appear in it's properties when I select the car image. Any help?

[Here is when in drawable Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icEij.png)

I have tried putting the image in utility folder Build action appears but not when I place it inside the drawable folder.

[Here is when not in drawable Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhHqv.png)

Comment: AFAIK items in the drawuable folders are handled automatically.  I never gave to set their Build Action

Comment: It will set the build action of the image to the `AndroidResource` when you put the image into the resource folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the picture you posted, and I found that it is caused by not putting the image files in the resource folder correctlly. Please check if you have put the images to the folder and do not just use it in the disk.

You can follow this document about [how to use the images in the Xamarin.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows)